# How to change authentication type in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created the project with no authentication now I want to change it to individual user authentication, I tried searching on google but no luck

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project with individual user authentication and copying the code over to your existing project?

Comment: @Balah that will be hard, moving all the models and controllers after that adding views and performing migrations

Comment: No, it won't be hard. You just need to look at a project that has the right code and implement it in yours. Bonus points, you learn something about what it actually needs. Asking us how to implement alternative authentication methods is too broad a question.